# Consuming ASMX from Console Application (.Net 4)

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have created a simple ASMX web service (void return value), which I have tested and works correctly. However, now I am attempting to create a console application which will simply consume the service.

In Visual Studio 2012, in my console application, I have right-clicked on the solution, clicked Add Service Reference, and added the service successfully. Then I added the following code to consume the service:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySvc.MySvcSoapClient proxy = new MySvc.MySvcSoapClient();
        proxy.CallService();
        proxy.Close();
    }
```

The above code compiles correctly, however, at runtime when it hits the proxy.CallService() line, it throws the following exception:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How is it that I can launch my web service directly from a browser and it works, but when I try to consume it, I am getting an error? I haven't been able to find much relevant help online.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: That being said, your problem is in the service, not in the client.